# Android web view don't open new tab link

Tags: android

I want to open links in the same WebView and I've overrided WebView's default web client as following:

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

And it works fine when I'm opening default links, but when I try to open link that was set to open in the new tab nothing is happening. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Try return false

Comment: Please upvote my answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override every other link by returning false.

Try return false instead of true